# Time difference using MySQL - end time after mid night not working

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to figure out whether my current time falls between two given times. It is working fine, unless if my end time falls **after the mid night**, while my start time is during the day.

For example, if I have:

*Start:* 17:00

*End:* 03:00

*Current:* **18:30**

It then will not show up.

I do understand where the logic is going wrong, but I can't find a fix for it, logically and conceptually. I mean, you could claim that 06:30 PM does fall between 05 PM and 03 AM, but then 03 AM of the next day!

How do we overcome that problem?

Here is my query below:

```
SELECT * FROM products
        JOIN restaurants
        ON (products.Venue = restaurants.name)
        WHERE products.Drink_Category = Beer
        AND restaurants.Area = Racks 
        AND (
        HOUR(18:30) >= HOUR(products.Start) -- here is where the time is set
        AND HOUR(18:30) <= HOUR(products.End) --and here is the end
        )
        ORDER BY products.Price/products.Multiple ASC;
```

I have as well tried `BETWEEN` query, and yet it does not work for those specific cases.

Comment: What SQL dialect is that?

Comment: @Lucero, It's rather MySQL, just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when `products.End` is smaller than `products.Start`, just add 24 to account for the day wrapping. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM products
    JOIN restaurants
    ON (products.Venue = restaurants.name)
    WHERE products.Drink_Category = Beer
    AND restaurants.Area = Racks 
    AND (
    HOUR(18:30) >= HOUR(products.Start) -- here is where the time is set
    AND HOUR(18:30) <= CASE
        WHEN products.End<products.Start 
        THEN HOUR(products.End)+24 
        ELSE HOUR(products.End) END --and here is the end
    )
    ORDER BY products.Price/products.Multiple ASC;
```

Comment: It didn't only work, it nailed it. What a query, thanks mate!

Comment: @Strawberry From the task description my assumption is "no" because it's about certain time-of-the-day ranges, and as such it is date-independent (which in consequence makes 24h correct for the wrap). Sina, correct me if I'm wrong. ;)

Comment: @Strawberry, I do understand your concern, but my only cases are between for e.g. 17:00 to 22:00, or 17:00 to 03:00, which two of the scenarios are then satisfied using the query above. Thanks for the help, both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 way:
1- use complete date time value in your Condition like this:

```
Select * FROM table_event where ((SaleDate >= @FromDate) AND (SaleDate < @ToDate)) Order by SaleDate DESC
```

2- you can change your condition in back end, if your end time go to tomorrow you must write another condition like this:

```
    (HOUR(18:30) >= HOUR(products.Start) AND HOUR(23:59) <= HOUR(products.End) )
    OR
   ( HOUR(00:00) >= HOUR(products.Start) AND HOUR(3:00) <= HOUR(products.End) )
```